# java.lang.NullPointerException Error when trying to set and editText widget

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I have a strange error, I get NullPointerException error when I set text to EditText.
Code is something like below:

```
EditText editTxt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);
    if(someCondition) {
        if (editTxt!=null)
            editTxt.setText("HelloWorld");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your logcat please.

Comment: Post your layout and Exception log please.

Comment: Please post the original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this small code,There should be one Error only

```
    editTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);
```

that your id in xml doesnot match  with edtTxt.If yes then try to clean it once then run

Comment: there is a check for `if(editTxt!=null)`, so it should not cause the exception.

Comment: when you will setValue then it gave exception.If you check it it did not satisfy null condition if(editTxt!=null)

Comment: //Got it working like this,

String hello = "HelloWorld!";

EditText editTxt;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

editTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);
if(someCondition)
{if(editTxt!=null)
editTxt.setText(hello);
}
}

Comment: so that means there was not error.Will you consider to accept this answer?

Answer (score 0):

The object that's cited in the stack trace wasn't initialized.  You never asked it to point to a new object on the heap.

I'm putting my money on that reference `R`.  I don't see where that's initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
EditText editTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text);

if (editTxt!=null) {
    editTxt.setText("HelloWorld");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Got it working like this, 
String hello = "HelloWorld!"; 
EditText editTxt; 
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    editTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTxt); 
    if(someCondition) {
        if(editTxt!=null) editTxt.setText(hello); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: No clue why string constant entered directly was not working thou !!